# Can I change mac to iterate over select items with down key like on Windows?

Tags: keyboard

On windows, all I needed to do in such a dropdown, when it was selected to press down button and it would select the next item, which would result in seeing the next color variant. You could go through all the colors like this neatly and quickly without disturbance.

On mac I have to press down to open up the selection, press down again to select the item and then Enter to see the result. Super annoying. Is there some way to modify this behavior to emulate the more efficient behavior from Windows?

See here, with button presses on Mac:

[image: https://media.giphy.com/media/FZTHr5IKUU15r0TbsA/giphy.gif]

[You can experiment with the UI on this link](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Nylon-Woven-Band-Strap-Easy-Fit-For-Garmin-Fenix-3-5-5X-Plus-6-6X-Pro-Sapphire/174341491091?hash=item2897900993%3Ag%3AJ04AAOSwKLdfBNpz&LH_BIN=1)

I am on macOS Big Sur and this undesirable behaviour was reproduced on Safari, Brave, Firefox (haven't gone further).

Comment: This works for me - what version of macOS and what browser are you using? (This has been baked into Mac menus since before Windows existed afaik, but maybe I’m using the software differently than you are.)

Comment: Tested Safari Mac & Edge Win10. Same behaviour on both. Arrow steps but new colour is not seen until you Return or click. eBay has always been like this afaik.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's not an eBay thing, I tested on Brave on Windows 10 and it jumps through colors with every downpress.

Comment: @bmike what specifically do you mean by "works for me"? Do you have to press down press twice and enter or is pressing down once enough to change the color? I have macOS Big Sur and this undesirable behavior is present in Firefox, Safari, Brave (haven't tested more)